# ordering an array based on values of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question is probably basic for some of you but it I am new to Python. I have an initial array:

```
initial_array = np.array ([1, 6, 3, 4])
```

I have another array.

```
value_array= np.array ([10, 2, 3, 15])
```

I want an array called output array which looks at the values in value_array and reorder the initial array.

My result should look like this:

```
output_array = np.array ([4, 1, 3, 6])
```

Does anyone know if this is possible to do in Python?

So far I have tried:

```
for i in range(4):
      find position of element
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to find sort_index from `value_array` then rearrange the `initial_array` base sort_index in the reversing order with `[::-1]`.

```
>>> idx_sort = value_array.argsort()
>>> initial_array[idx_sort[::-1]]
array([4, 1, 3, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use stack to put arrays together - basically adding column to initial array, then sort by that column.

```
import numpy as np

initial_array =  np.array ([1, 6, 3, 4])

value_array =  np.array ([10, 2, 3, 15])

output_array = np.stack((initial_array, value_array), axis=1)

output_array=output_array[output_array[:, 1].argsort()][::-1]
print (output_array)
```

[::-1] part is for descending order. Remove to get ascending.
I am assuming initial_array and values_array will have same length.